# Actor MDC context in aroundReceive method

Tags: java, akka, mdc

I have a Java Akka application and I want to set a separate MDC context for each message handling based on information inside the message, for example I have the following base interface for all messages:

```
public interface IdMessage {
    String getId();
}
```

Also I have the following base actor for all actors:

```
public class BaseActor extends AbstractActor {

    private final DiagnosticLoggingAdapter log = Logging.apply(this);

    @Override
    public void aroundReceive(PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof IdMessage) {
            final Map<String, Object> originalMDC = log.getMDC();
            log.setMDC(ImmutableMap.of("id", ((IdMessage) msg).getId()));
            try {
                super.aroundReceive(receive, msg);
            } finally {
                if (originalMDC != null) {
                    log.setMDC(originalMDC);
                } else {
                    log.clearMDC();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.aroundReceive(receive, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And the actual actor implementation:

```
public class SomeActor extends BaseActor {
    SomeActor() {
    receive(ReceiveBuilder
                    .match(SomeMessage.class, message -> {
                        ...
                     }
    }
}
```

I would like to make sure that all logs entries inside `SomeActor#receive()` will have MDC context set in the `BaseActor`. To make this work `SomeActor#receice()`  need to be executed in the same thread as `BaseActor#aroundReceive()` method.

I didn't find any information about the behaviour of `aroundReceive` - is that going to be always executed in the same thread as the actual `receive` method? Based on my testing it's always executed in the same thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the proper implementation by myself and would like to share it in case someone face with the same issue.

The `aroundReceive` is going to be executed in the same thread as `receive`, so this is the right place to set MDC context.

I used `org.slf4j.MDC` for setting the MDC context, here is the full code:

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import scala.PartialFunction;
import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;

public class BaseActor extends AbstractActor {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseActor.class);

    @Override
    public void aroundReceive(PartialFunction<Object, BoxedUnit> receive, Object msg) {
        if (msg instanceof IdMessage) {
            final Map<String, Object> originalMDC = log.getMDC();
            MDC.setContextMap(ImmutableMap.of("id", ((IdMessage) msg).getId()));
            try {
                super.aroundReceive(receive, msg);
            } finally {
                if (originalMDC != null) {
                    MDC.setContextMap(originalMDC);
                } else {
                    MDC.clear();
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.aroundReceive(receive, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

With that implementation of `BaseActor` all log entries in `receive` are logged with a proper MDC context. Additional information could be found in this interesting blog [post](http://code.hootsuite.com/logging-contextual-info-in-an-asynchronous-scala-application/) (with Scala implementation).

Note: I was not able to reach the same functionality with Akka `DiagnosticLoggingAdapter` although it has methods to set MDC context.

Comment: The reasons why `DiagnosticLoggingAdapter` doesn't do the trick are explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31237679/843660). As for overriding `aroundReceive`, this is marked as internal API and only works if you put your class in package `akka.actor`, which is a hack. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26723452/843660). Not sure what can be done in Java though.